# get the value of label in a button click in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, row

I am displaying the data returned from a webservice client side in a jquery dialog ,dynamically in a table kind of structure  each row also has a button to select the values of the row and return it back to the main window

```
 $("<div/>")
        .attr({ "class": "line dataRow ProductSearchResultRow",
            "custom:id": vProdLines[i].id,
            "custom:title": vProdLines[i].title,
            "custom:composer": vProdLines[i].composer,
            "custom:performer": vProdLines[i].performer,
            "custom:rec": vProdLines[i].rec
        })
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size3p" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].rec)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size1of5" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].title)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size1of8" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].composer)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size1of8" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].arranger)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size1of8" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].performer)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size1of10" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].publisher)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size8p" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].label)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size8p" }).html($("<label/>").html(vProdLines[i].catNo)))
        .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size5p" })

                    .append($("<div/>").attr({ "class": "unit size1of10" })
                           .append($("<input/>")
                                    .attr({ "type": "button" })
                                    .val("Select")
                                    .click(function () {
                                        $("div.ProdSearchResultRow").removeClass("SelectedRow");
                                        $(this).addClass("SelectedRow");
                                        $("#newProdTitleId").val($(this).attr("custom:id"));
                                        $("input#txtProdSheetSelectedMusicTitle").val($(this).attr("custom:title"));
                                        $("input#txtProdSheetSelectedComposer").val($(this).attr("custom:composer"));
                                        $("input#txtProdSheetSelectedPerformer").val($(this).attr("custom:performer"));
                                        $("#tdProdNewRec").children("select").val($(this).attr("custom:rec"));
                                        ClosePopupBox("modalProdSearch");
```

it all is getting displaying well and the dialog also closes but I am unable to get the values of the 
row which are in the label inside each div element.

I have understood that using 'this' will actually point to button and not the main div but unable to get values of  row when button is clicked.

rendered page html is like this:

```
<div class="line dataRow MusicSearchResultRow" id="myid_1452708" id="myid_1452708"
    custom:title="TEST" custom:id="1452708" custom:composer="AL" custom:performer="AL"
    custom:rec="C">
    <div class="unit size3p">
        <label>
            C</label></div>
    <div class="unit size1of5">
        <label>
            TEST</label></div>
    <div class="unit size1of8">
        <label>
            AL</label></div>
    <div class="unit size1of8">
        <label>
            AL</label></div>
    <div class="unit size1of8">
        <label>
            AL</label></div>
    <div class="unit size1of10">
        <label>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="unit size8p">
        <label>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="unit size8p">
        <label>
            1234</label></div>
    <div class="unit size5p">
        <input type="button" value="info"></div>
    <div class="unit size1of10">
        <input type="button" value="Select"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="divProdSearchBox" class="line ProdList" style="overflow:auto; margin-left:6px;"></div>
                             </div></div>                                    the dynamic code is added to this div "divProdSearchBox"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving an id to your div and getting the attr from that?

```
$("<div/>")
    .attr({ "id": "myid",
       "class": "line dataRow ProductSearchResultRow", //rest of it
```

and then on your button click replace

```
$(this).attr(
```

with

```
$("#myid").attr(
```

id needs to be qunique though so you might need to do something like

```
$("<div/>")
    .attr({ "id": "myid_" + vProdLines[i].id,
```

and in button click

```
$("#myid_" + vProdLines[i].id).attr(
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried this but got this error "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: In button click can you add these lines and see what you get: console.log("prodlineid: " + vProdLines[i].id); console.log("div: " + $("#myid_" + vProdLines[i].id);

Comment: sorry, try this, before $("<div/>").attr add: var divId = vProdLines[i].id; then add id attr as $("<div/>").attr({ "id": "myid_" + divId, and finally in button click do $("#myid_" + divId).attr(

Comment: Tried this . In the button click I added an alert to check the value and it always returns the value of the last row attributes. I debugged and found that it adds values alright in each loop but when I click select button in any row, it returns the last row values.

Comment: We'll sort this out :) Forget about the id, add a class to your top div, i.e. $("<div/>").attr({ "class": "topDivClass", then in your button click use $(this).closest(".topDivClass").attr(

Answer (score 0):

To isolate instance `this` will be the element clicked, then you can use `closest()` to get the row instance.

Once you have the row instance you can use `find()` within the row to access other elements of that row

```
$("<input/>")
    .attr({
    "type": "button"
})
    .val("Select")
    .click(function () {
    var $buttonClicked = $(this),
        $closestRow = $buttonClicked.closest('.ProdSearchResultRow');

    var $anotherElementInThisRow = $closestRow.find('.someClass');
});
```

Get acquainted with the [traversal methods section of the API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).